# Remove elements with text using lxml

Tags: lxml

I have the following xml file

```
<xml>
  <network id="5">
    <nodelist>
      <IP>10.10.0.135::3111</IP>
      <IP>10.10.0.130::3111</IP>
      <IP>10.10.0.129::3111</IP>
      <IP>10.10.0.129::3111</IP>
    </nodelist>
    <nodelist2/>
  </network>
</xml>
```

I want to remove all the elements with IP 10.10.0.129 where network id=5. How can I do it in lxml?

Currently, I'm trying to find the nodes using xpath and I'm trying to remove it.

But,

```
netid=xml.xpath("network[@id=%s]/nodelist/IP[contains(text(),%s)]"%(id,node))
```

Gives me error `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`.

Comment: I assume you are using python since the lxml homepage says "The lxml XML toolkit is a Pythonic binding for the C libraries libxml2 and libxslt."

Comment: I normally don't post two answers, but in this case, one gives you entire xml without the specific elements, and the other gives just the wanted ip elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a python programmer, so I have it coded in python 2.7.  If you need to use a different language, you will have to port it yourself since I don't do anything but Python.

Note, although this seemingly deals with xpath, most of my processing is done with python.

```
import lxml.etree as etree  #import etree, like c's include

def delete(xml,networkid,ipaddr):
    tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
    networks = tree.findall('.//network[@id="%s"]'%str(networkid)) #I think you forgot the quotes in your insertion.  
    for network in networks:  #for each network that has id='5'.
        ips = network.findall('.//IP') #All the IP elements under the network
        for ip in ips:  #iterating through a list of ips
            if ipaddr in ip.text:  #if ipaddr is inside the text, even if a port is appended
                ip.getparent().remove(ip)  #the ip's parent (nodelist) removes the ip element
return tree  # I give you the tree


s = r'''<xml>  #Here's your original xml
  <network id="5">
    <nodelist>
      <IP>10.10.0.135::3111</IP>
      <IP>10.10.0.130::3111</IP>
      <IP>10.10.0.129::3111</IP>
      <IP>10.10.0.129::3111</IP>
    </nodelist>
    <nodelist2/>
  </network>
</xml>'''

res = delete(s,'5','10.10.0.129')  #here's the result
print res  #and it's a tree.
print list(res.iter())  #so I print all the items under it.
print etree.tostring(res)  #and you have your edited xml.
```

Comment: Hope I helped.  Note:  This is lxml (2.3 I believe) running with Python 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

This should be it.

```
tree.xpath(r'''network[@id="%s"]/nodelist/IP[not(contains(text(),"%s"))]'''%('5','10.10.0.129'))
```

Where the stuff between the triple-single-quotes is your xpath code (I tested with python so I have to).  This gives you all the IP elements with your specifications.  Apparently python's lxml.etree.xml.xpath won't let me remove, but this will give you everything else.

Comment: "tree" is my name for the xml object

Answer (score 0):

Using lxml under Python2.7:

```
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_fragment) ## Or tree = ET.parse(somefile)

for rn in tree.xpath('network[@id="5"]//IP[starts-with(text(),"10.10.0.129:")]'):
    rn.getparent().remove(rn)
```